Meaning of 時は廻る
From the end of quintessential quintuplets chapter 54

I am not sure what それぞれの時は廻{めぐ}り means here. I am more familiar with expressions like 一時を回る, which means 一時を過ぎる. I wonder if it is the case here.

廻る is essentially just a fancier version of (時が)経つ or (時が)来る. It's preferred in literary, dramatic, or poetic contexts, and is used to express the passage of a long period of time (months, years, or decades).

When used in these contexts, how often is it read as めぐる vs まわる?

@istrasci 時がまわる makes little sense to me.
